# YQL Returning Bad Results on Email Age Search

Tags: yql

For the last few weeks our team has been unable to return email age results from YQL.

I'm hoping someone here has a workaround or answer for us.

We've been using the following string:

> select * from social.profile where guid in (select guid from yahoo.identity where yid='email@Yahoo.com')

Previously, it would return profile results including date of creation. Now the results for every email we attempt looks as if the email doesn't exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the rest query.